# API values to set opacity levels to show overlapping points in highcharts scatter?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Looking at the demo for scatter charts I can see what when two points overlap they become more opaque: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter

[image: nice visual indicator of overlap/density]

I'm pulling data in from fields on a Drupal site, which is then building the JSON to feed to Highcharts via a contributed module which overrides the alpha transparency values and just outputs opaque / opacity = 1 `<path>` elements. I was able to feed the opacity back to the chart via passing in the proper API option ala `$chart['series'][0]['opacity'] = .6;` however the overlapping areas of points don't turn into something like .8 like I would expect:

[image: no fancy opacity]

I haven't been able to find the API call to manage this, is there some way I can pass a value via plotOptions.scatter.overlap or whatever to get this behaviour back?

**update**: there's transparency between series, but not on the markers between them - which makes sense as I'm applying opacity at the series level and there isn't an option for it at the marker level as far as I can tell.

[image: opacity overlap between series but not within them]

@Sebastian Hajdus's answer doesn't solve the issue, as the default for `lineColor` is actually #fff (white), and `fillColor` being null just inherits the color from series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[series.scatter.color](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.color)  ended up being the value I needed to change marker opacity on scatter charts using the API.

Sadly there's no fillOpacity for scatter charts ala [series.bubble.marker.fillOpacity](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.marker.fillOpacity) which would have made my life easier.

Passing the following lines worked for me:

```
$chart['series'][0]['color'] = 'rgba(83, 223, 83, .5)';
$chart['series'][1]['color'] = 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)';
$chart['series'][2]['color'] = 'rgba(83, 83, 223, .5)';
```

Answer (score 1):

Fill propertyies `lineColor` and `fillColor` in the `null` to enable the default settings.

```
  plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
      opacity: 0.5,
      marker: {
        radius: 20,
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: null,
        fillColor: null,
      }
    }
  },
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tbpn63uc/1/

Comment: That doesn't fix it for me - interestingly enough both with and without `lineColor` and `fillColor` there is the desired behaviour between series, but not witihin them (bumping the radius up to 20 for testing purposes clarified that).

Could it be there's something else from series.scatter I need to set?

https://imgur.com/a/5axCP3E

Comment: any thoughts?


  `$chart['plotOptions']['scatter']['marker']['radius'] = 20;`
  `$chart['plotOptions']['scatter']['marker']['lineColor'] = NULL;`
  `$chart['plotOptions']['scatter']['marker']['fillColor'] = NULL;`
  `$chart['plotOptions']['scatter']['dataLabels']['enabled'] = FALSE;`

radius and borderlabels effect the chart as expected.

Comment: The default for `lineColor`is actually #fff (white), and `fillColor` being null just inherits the color from series, so I don't think those two values would impact anything.

Comment: In this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tbpn63uc/2/) I recreated the state you have now and you want to get the state when the shadows overlap yes? Could you adapt my demo to your case and we will try to solve this.

Comment: Yeah, that example mimics what I have now.

I'm pretty sure what's happening is that the Drupal CMS is hard passing colors in a way that strips them of their alpha values, using your fiddle [passing rgba in fillColor fixes the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/erutan/0rhvz3uk/). 

Interestingly enough bubble charts work as expected.

[scatter charts markers](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.marker) don't have fillOpacity like bubble charts, that'd likely solve my issue [series.bubble.marker.fillOpacity](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.marker.fillOpacity)

Comment: I imagine setting the color at series with RGBa values would be my best bet.

Something like `$chart['series'][0]['color'] = 'rbga(0,255,0,.5)';`